# How to get Kerberos Authentication on my HDFS Web UI?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

Wanting to secure the Hadoop web UI. NOT USING AMBARI. RHEL 7 single node cluster. Parameters are shown in images from my core-site.xml and security auth error on web UI shown in image as well. My goal here is to either set a login screen to the web UI or use Kerberos to grant user authentication token. On this RHEL box, kinit username then typing in AD password works fine and krbtgt AD account grants ticket to said username. There is something I am missing or my parameters are incorrectly set. Please assist on adding security to my Hadoop cluster's web UI. Thanks! (Note: cookie domain param is my domain name & Kerberos principal param is the value I was returned from klist after kinit username)

[WEB UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqvNG.jpg)

[Half of my core-site.xml params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiBV2.jpg)

[Other half of my core-site.xml params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uV21.jpg)

Tried to set the http security parameters. Was expecting login page to web UI or to just get authenticated through AD / kerberos to web UI, however, that is not the result currently.

Comment: Apache Knox does this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, am I that far off that I should start over and go with the Knox solution? I felt like I was close enough that I could just change a few things and get my current solution to work. If not possible, sure I will look further into Knox.

Comment: Knox is a proxy with SPNEGO/Kerberos protection for all Hadoop related web interfaces